# Is it okay to add parameters to a URL after a trailing slash

Tags: url, url-parameters, trailing-slash

For example:

http://www.example.com/dashboard/?utm_source=mySource&utm_medium=Mobile&utm_campaign=myCampagin

My goal is to add Analytics tags to all the links in my site.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to add parameters to url, after the trailing slash is the preferred place. I believe you can specify parameters in Google Analytics so that Google can recognize that each url with different parameters is not an entirely new page.